# In 8.0.17 EPSG Spatial reference systems are not available at installation?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, spatial, mysql-8.0

In 8.0.17 INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ST_SPATIAL_REFERENCE_SYSTEMS is not prepopulated with ORGANIZATION="EPSG" records, leaving the table with only a single record, that for the default SRID=0.

A count in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ST_SPATIAL_REFERENCE_SYSTEMS of 1 record instead of the 5152 records found in 8.0.15.

It's breaking my load scripts with the following error due to the previously available spacial reference systems being omitted.

```
ERROR 3548 (SR001) at line 1: There's no spatial reference system with SRID 4326.
```

Is this a documented intentional change, or am I missing something?

This is not mentioned in the release notes:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-16.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-17.html

My installations are both default AWS RDS installations made at different times resulting in different mysql versions. The reference systems are present on the prior installation but missing on the second.

version   8.0.15
innodb_version    8.0.15

```
SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ST_SPATIAL_REFERENCE_SYSTEMS;
5152
```

version   8.0.17
innodb_version    8.0.17

```
SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ST_SPATIAL_REFERENCE_SYSTEMS;
1
```

Comment: My docker version of 8.0.17 has 5152 entries.  I don't see anything relevant in any of the 8.0 changelogs.  Suggest you file a bug at bugs.mysql.com .

Comment: @EvanCarroll It's definitely the same issue, though the answer to date, requires reverting to an 8.015 database and upgrading forward, however lightsail only offers 8.0.17 and not 8.0.15. It can be done directly in RDS, but is a clumbsy process.